# Search first word in string mysql

Tags: mysql

### I have strings in column like that

```
+-----------------+
| col             |
+-----------------+
| {Cat}{bat}{hat} |
| {bat}{hat}{Cat} |
| {sat}{Cat}{jat} |
| {Cat}{mat}      |
+-----------------+
```

### Searching first and forth

I want to search only first and forth because both are starting with `{cat}`.

Comment: `select * from table where column like {cat}%`

Comment: Vijay but it will search if cat on second position

Comment: @DeepanshuGarg - can you give some real examples of what you're trying to filter out? Vijajkumar Hadalgis select should work as you expect. Are you trying directly in mysql (in console or phpmyadmin or similar?) or  are you trying through some server side language like php?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table where column like '%{Cat}%'
```

if you need only starting with cat then

use

```
 select * from table where column like '{Cat}%'
```

Comment: It will Select 3rd one too

Comment: @Sajad  but it will search second and thrid also. I don't want search on second and thrid forth position. I need those string having first position

Comment: `%` should be after the `{cat}` not before that

Comment: @DeepanshuGarg:check now.!!

Comment: @Sajad It is searching second and third also

Comment: @DeepanshuGarg which one you used ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * From yourTable where ColumnName like '{cat}%'
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/197cf/1)**

Op:

```
MYCOLUMN
+-------------+
{Cat}{bat}{hat}
{Cat}{mat}
```

Comment: This would only give results that starts with [cat}

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Yes He need that only.So it will return 1st and 4th

Comment: But i need a string start with {cat} not second and thrid no {cat}

Comment: @DeepanshuGarg Yes use my query It will return 1st and 4 th

Comment: Confusing, it seems like OP is changing his mind all the time ;-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Check my fiddle

Comment: @VigneshKumar - I didn't disbelieve you. I said that it would give results that starts with {cat} :-) (But I'm not sure OP is expressing himself what he really want)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Column LIKE '{Cat}%'
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. *I want to search only first and forth because both are starting with {cat}.*
> 2. *But i need a string start with `{cat}` not second and thrid no `{cat}`*

If I understand correct, you are expecting:

1. word set that start with `'{cat}'`,
2. remove starting word `'{cat}'` from the results

Try this:

```
select 
  colName, 
  substr( colName, 1+length( '{cat}' ) ) as modified_str
from your_table
where 
  colName like '{cat}%'
;
```

It will return:

```
+-----------------+--------------+
| colName         | modified_str |
+-----------------+--------------+
| {Cat}{bat}{hat} | {bat}{hat}   |
| {Cat}{mat}      | {mat}        |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

***See***: [***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ba48/2)